# How can I create keybindings on a non-graphical console?

Tags: debian, terminal, keyboard

My keyboard is unable to produce a "|". On XFCE xbindkeys works very well (I mapped it to Alt + z), but I couldn't do the same on the non-graphical tty. How can I do that?

I'm on MX Linux 17.

Comment: Have a look here for inspiration/guidance: https://askubuntu.com/questions/485454/how-to-remap-keys-on-a-user-level-both-with-and-without-x

Answer (score 2):

You can change the console keyboard VT keymap with `loadkeys`. Use `dumpkeys|grep z` to see the current setting for the `z` character. It is probably:

```
keycode  44 = z
```

Then override it for <kbd>alt</kbd> with

```
echo 'alt keycode 44 = bar' | sudo loadkeys -
```

You might check first whether `bar` exists already in some key combination.